# What is lagrangian?

Tags: svm, mathematics

I'm watching an [SVM tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/support-vector-machine-fundamentals-machine-learning-tutorial/?completed=/support-vector-assertions-machine-learning-tutorial/b).

At 6:38 he mentions `lagrangian`, which is a term I'm not familiar with.

So I googled it, hoping to find the Wikipedia article about it, but it seems like this term is actually ambiguous, and Wikipedia suggests several articles.

Which of the [suggested articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian) should I read in order to understand the meaning of `lagrangian` in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is referring to [Lagrangian Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), an optimization technique for problems with equality constraints.